# Estimating conditional probability when events are sampled

Tags: probability, estimation, conditional-probability, estimators

Suppose I have many people who eat different fruits (apples, oranges, bananas &c):

```
Person   Apples Oranges Bananas ...
Alice     2      3       0
Bob       0      0       3
Charlie   3      0       0
David     0      1       7
...
```

(i.e., Bob ate neither apples nor oranges but only 3 bananas).

**How do I estimate** $$P(\text{person ate an Apple}\ |\ \text{person ate an Orange})$$

It would seem reasonable to say that since there are 2 persons who ate Oranges (Alice and David) and only one who ate both (Alice), the estimate is 1/2. More generally, if `df` is a pandas [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), then `((df.Apples > 0) & (df.Oranges > 0)).sum() / (df.Oranges > 0).sum()` is an unbiased estimate of the conditional probability.

Now, suppose the data is *incomplete* and we observe only $p=1\%$ of all fruit **consumption events**. I.e., I have 1% of the records `(person,fruit)` that represent one eating (the table above corresponds to 19 such records).

How do I estimate the above quantity as a function of $p$ and the observed data? (the same formula will be an underestimate, right?)

**PS1**. Collecting more data is not an option. *However*, one can avoid this problem altogether by a *person-based sampling*, i.e., ensuring that **if** a person appears in the sample at all, then **all** his eatings are also in the sample.

**PS2**. Addition and omission of people like Bob in the table above obviously cannot affect the result.

**PS3**. [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4233207/37092).

Comment: Is the data missing completely at random? What kind of N are you looking at for each person? If you only have 1% of the data for each person who ate 100 fruits, you won't able to learn much at all from the (on average) 1 fruit each person ate that was recorded. If you have 1% of the data for each person who each ate 100k fruits, on the other hand, you can apply the exact same approach to reason about the 1000 fruits recorded for each person (assuming no sampling bias).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: (1) yes, random by _eatings_ (2) what is $N$?

Comment: $N$ is sample size. If everybody only ate (on average) 100 fruits, 1% subsampling is a big problem because now you have (on average) 1 fruit recorded for each person and no ability whatsoever to do conditional probability. If you have 1% of a very large sample, however, it's absolutely no different from having 100% of a reasonably-sized cohort. If the data is missing completely at random, it's impossible to distinguish your complete example data from the 1% subset of a dataset 100x as large.

Comment: Basically, you've shown a good approach to conditional probability on the example data. If you revealed that the example data was actually a random subset of a larger dataset, it would not change the validity of your approach or findings. Having a random subset makes it harder to estimate the values precisely, but doesn't change how you do it.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I have ~1B `(person,fruit)` _observations_. However, I also have millions of people in the sample. Some ate 10k fruit, some 3. Thus it is likely that there will be people for whom I observed eating oranges but _not_ apples, so my formula will underestimate the conditional probability.